# Nested operations on list of redis in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

i am using llen and inside llen i am using lindex in node_redis. Inside lindex the response is undefined.

```
 redisClient.llen("Device_Live", function (errorMessage, activeDevice) {
    for (var i= 0; i< activeDevice; i++) {
        redisClient.lindex("Device_Live", i, function (errorMessage, deviceList)     
        {
           console.log(deviceList);
        });
    }
});
```

How can I make it run correct.

Comment: I tried you code and everything is fine.

Comment: but not working for me..

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. Is this code an exact copy/paste of your real code? I suspect that you may have a typo in your code.

Comment: yes this code is copy/paste from my code. I am using Redis on windows 64 bit

Comment: Do you use hiredis by any chance?